# Page Name and Permalinks

Tags: permalinks

I am using WordPress 3.2.1 and just added a page to my site called "Centre Management", which in turn created a permalink:

http://localhost:8888/mysite/centre-management/

for that page I just created.

After this, I trashed this page and wanted to start again. So when I now create another new page with the same name as above, i.e. "Centre Management", WordPress now creates me a permalink of:

‎http://localhost:8888/mysite/centre-management-2/

which is not what I am after. I would like it to appear as:

http://localhost:8888/mysite/centre-management/

Can you please let me know how I can go about preventing these sequence numbers appearing after I recreate a page with the same name?

I would always like to to use the page name only.

FYI, I have a .htaccess file and am using the following Permalinks structure in my sites:

Custom Structure: /http:/localhost:8888/mysite/post-name/

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to permanently delete the post from the trash to be able to use that permalink again.

At the top of the pages list, where it says All, Published, Trash, click trash and then select permanently delete link for that page.